# Updating historical prices in quantmod

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Quantmod's getSymbols() fetches historical prices up till yesterday's close. I do my analysis in the morning and would like to update the series with the current quote (I only use adjusted prices). I can't seem to get it to work. When I use this code :

```
getSymbols('AGNC')
q <- getQuote('AGNC')
d <- Sys.Date()
qq<- q$Last
x <- zoo(qq,d)
t <- rbind.zoo(Ad(AGNC), x)
print(tail(t))
```

It prints out OK, but when I try to do something further, like:

```
dum <- dailyReturn(t)
```

I get the following error:

Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "daily.returns") : 
  attempt to set colnames on object with less than two dimensions

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you open to using `xts` instead of `zoo`?

Comment: Yes, xts would be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols('AGNC')
q <- getQuote('AGNC')
d <- Sys.Date()
qq<- q$Last
x <- xts(qq,d)
t <- rbind(Ad(AGNC), x)
print(tail(t))
dailyReturn(t)
```

Comment: seealso: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/attachments/20111103/3ec182ca/attachment.pl

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to update a symbol:

```
require(quantmod)
getSymbols('AGNC')

q <- getQuote('AGNC')
row.names(q)<- trunc(q[,"Trade Time"], units="days")
q <- q[,c("Open","High","Low","Last","Volume","Last")]
names(q) <- c("Open","High","Low","Close","Volume","Adjusted")
AGNC <- merge(AGNC,q,by="Date")
print(last(AGNC))
dailyReturn(AGNC)
```